# Using the triangle inequality

Tags: maxima, inequality

Is it possible to get Maxima to use the triangle inequality to assess inequalities?

For example to get true for simple inequalities like

```
is( abs(x-1) + 1 >= abs(x) );
```

I use Maxima in STACK. There are some globally forbidden commands (see https://github.com/maths/moodle-qtype_stack/blob/master/stack/cas/casstring.class.php#L92).

Comment: I found `fourier_elim` to be useful. Unfortunately loading functions or libraries is not possible in STACK, hence I can't use for example `to_poly_solve`.